# Search string in multiple files using c#

Tags: c#

I want to search word or string in multiple file in directory.
for example "Error" , "Warning"  If any file contain any of three word then it should print messages.all files in same directory.

With this code I can search one word in single file but I want to search all d file which are available in directory.

```
      List<string> found = new List<string>();
         string line;
         using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text))
         {
             while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
             {
                 if (line.Contains("Error: 1"))
                 {
                     found.Add(line);
        MessageBox.Show("Error Found");
                 }
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, string> found = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string line;
bool textFound = false;
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles("path-to-directory"))
{
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename))
    {

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("Error: 1"))
            {
                found.Add(line,filename);
                MessageBox.Show("Error Found");
                textFound = true;
            }
            if (line.Contains("Warning: 1"))
            {
                found.Add(line,filename);
                MessageBox.Show("Warning Found");
                textFound = true;
            }
        }          
    }  

}
if(!textFound)
           MessageBox.Show("Your message here");
```

Comment: but here i want to search two words...if any one word found in any file then it should print message.

Comment: @user1753911 added check for second word too

Comment: can we use else instead of second IF  ?

Comment: @SagarTrivedi why else? these are two separate cases. One is false that doesnt mean other will be true

Comment: i want bcz there is one more scenario like If there is no errors and no warnings then it should print diff message. @aksheyBhat

Comment: this is i already tried but its printing only last Else statement wether condition is true or not.

Comment: @SagarTrivedi There was a mistake in my logic. Modified code to fix it

Comment: No brother..same thing happen...if there is no error & no warning then it should print last IF statement but here in this code always printing last IF statement.

Comment: did u run or check bcz same thing happen.

Comment: please check if you are supplying correct search string to contains function

Comment: suppose i remove last IF then its working fine but when put last IF then its printing  only last IF statement.

Comment: That's because all message boxes are overlapped over each other. Message box are shown one over the other. There will be one message box for each of the files where text is not found.

Comment: yeah  got your point..instead of message i took 2 diff label..but the last statement always coming.

Comment: I was showing message if text was not found after searching a single file. Now i have modified code to show message after searching in all files

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expresion:

```
Regex.Match(line, @"\b(Error: 1|Warning: 1|Others)\b");
```